How to render the label of a lightning-button in a lightning-datatable but disable the lightning-button onclick functionality itself?
This is linked somewhat to the questions here and here.
I have a lightning-datatable that has a column that is a lightning-button which, when clicked, invokes a lightning-modal.
The UX behavior that I ideally want is that if the character size of a field is below 20 characters, then disable the lightning-button because there's not a value-add to click on the lightning-modal. However, if the field is above 20 characters, then display a truncated value of 20 characters and have the lightning-button enabled as there is a value-add to see the full contents in the modal.
{
    label: 'Description',
    type: 'button',
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'Description' },
        name: 'view_description',
        title: 'Click to see the full description',
        iconPosition: 'center',
        variant: 'base',
        disabled: {fieldName: 'DescriptionValueLessThanCharacterLimit'}
    },
}

However, if the DescriptionValueLessThanCharacterLimit is true then the contents of that column for that particular row in the lightning-datatable doesn't display anything, presumably because the lightning-button is disabled; which does make sense but is there a way to have the label of the button display?
I don't think that there is and it seems I'd either have to have an 'all or nothing' (i.e. if the Description is less than 20 characters, also have the ability to open the modal OR add a new column that conditionally reads 'View More' which is the lightning-button but have the contents of the Description field in a text column instead).
